# Add new column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm pretty much new to python so please except typos and all.

I am trying to add the new column in data frame based on the certain condition of the different column. so instead of returning values, it is returning a string which I'm just passing.

I don't know why it's happening and how to get rid of from that.

screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGVXu.png)shot attached.

vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"]=vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"].astype(int)

```
    vdx_access_table["Delivered_Impressions"]=vdx_access_table["Delivered_Impressions"].astype(int)

    choices_vdx_eng = vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"]/vdx_access_table["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"]

    choices_vdx_cpcv = vdx_access_table["Delivered_Impressions"]/vdx_access_table["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"]

    vdx_access_table['Delivery%']=[choices_vdx_eng if x=='CPE' or x=='CPE+' else choices_vdx_cpcv for x in
                                   vdx_access_table['COST_TYPE']]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
choices_vdx_eng=vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"]/vdx_access_table['BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG'] 
choices_vdx_imp=vdx_access_table["Delivered_Impressions"]/vdx_access_table['BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG'] 

mask = vdx_access_table['COST_TYPE'].isin(['CPE','CPE+'])
vdx_access_table['Delivery%']= np.where(mask, choices_vdx_eng, choices_vdx_imp )
```

Or:

```
mask = vdx_access_table['COST_TYPE'].isin(['CPE','CPE+'])
vdx_access_table['Delivery%']= np.where(mask, 
                                        vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"], 
                                        vdx_access_table["Delivered_Impressions"]) /vdx_access_table['BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG']
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Delivered_Engagements':[10,20,30,40,50],
                   'Delivered_Impressions':[5,4,8,7,3],
                   'BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG':[3,2,0,4,2],
                   'COST_TYPE':['CPE','CPE+','CPM','CPCV','AAA']})

df["Delivered_Engagements"]=df["Delivered_Engagements"].astype(int)
df["Delivered_Impressions"]=df["Delivered_Impressions"].astype(int)

eng = df["Delivered_Engagements"]/df["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"]
cpcv = df["Delivered_Impressions"]/df["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"]

mask1 = df["COST_TYPE"].isin(['CPE','CPE+'])
mask2 = df["COST_TYPE"].isin(['CPM','CPCV'])


df['Delivery%']=np.select([mask1, mask2], [eng, cpcv], default=0)

df['Delivery%']=df['Delivery%'].replace(np.inf,0)

print (df)
   BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG COST_TYPE  Delivered_Engagements  \
0                      3       CPE                     10   
1                      2      CPE+                     20   
2                      0       CPM                     30   
3                      4      CPCV                     40   
4                      2       AAA                     50   

   Delivered_Impressions  Delivery%  
0                      5   3.333333  
1                      4  10.000000  
2                      8   0.000000  
3                      7   1.750000  
4                      3   0.000000
```

Comment: both of them not working and first one is giving type error.

Comment: getting type error "TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types"

Comment: giving error on "choices_vdx_eng=vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"]/vdx_access_table["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"]" this line

Comment: @dharmendramishra - And your code working? `choices_vdx_eng=vdx_access_table.loc[:,["Delivered_Engagements"]]/vdx_access_table.loc[:,['BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG']]` ?

Comment: Yes its working however its not giving expected output values only returning string

Comment: @dharmendramishra what is `print(vdx_access_table.dtypes)` ?

Comment: PLACEMENT#                       object
START_DATE               datetime64[ns]
END_DATE                 datetime64[ns]
PLACEMENT_NAME                   object
COST_TYPE                        object
UNIT_COST                       float64
PLANNED_COST                    float64
BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG             int64
Delivered_Engagements            object
Delivered_Impressions             int64
dtype: object

Comment: Thank you, try `vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"] = vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"].astype(int)` before my code.

Comment: Thank you so much, its working fine now. Would you please let me know how to handle inf values coming in newly added column?

Comment: @dharmendramishra - you get `inf`, because divide by `0`. What do you want to do with `inf` ? Replace? Remove rows with `inf`? Something else?

Comment: replace with "0" or "-"

Comment: @dharmendramishra - You need `vdx_access_table['Delivery%'] = vdx_access_table['Delivery%'].replace(np.inf, 0)`

Comment: Thank you so much and such a nice solution. I've edited my code would you please why it is giving "unexpected argument" error when i'm passing more fields.

Comment: @dharmendramishra - Then need `np.select`, but there is more conditions?

Comment: @dharmendramishra - How it working is possible find e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48932972/2901002).

Comment: See my edit code, its producing an value error "ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions"

Comment: @dharmendramishra - hmmm, you need list of conditions and list of outputs. How do you want by one condition create many columns? Can you explain more?

Comment: Not getting the question here. but I want is to add one column on data frame based on some values of the different column. the values are four currently, however, they might increase or decrease. based on those values I want some calculation on the added column from different columns. so this is same as an example you have provided earlier for np.select.

Comment: @dharmendramishra - I dont understand, `choices_vdx_eng = vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"]/vdx_access_table["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"]
choices_vdx_deep = vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"]/vdx_access_table["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"]
choices_vdx_imp = vdx_access_table["Delivered_Impressions"]/vdx_access_table["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"]
choices_vdx_cpcv = vdx_access_table["Delivered_Impressions"]/vdx_access_table["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"]` is correct? because it seems first 2 are same as last 2

Comment: yes, I have created those because of this. "mask = vdx_access_table["COST_TYPE"].isin(['CPE','CPE+','CPM','CPCV'])"

Comment: @dharmendramishra - Please check edited answer. I think it is not necessary create 4 , only 2 Series are necessary.

Comment: Yes, its working fine now. so how it's identifying that, I have to do this calculation "vdx_access_table["Delivered_Engagements"]/vdx_access_table["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"] choices_vdx_imp = " or that calculation "vdx_access_table["Delivered_Impressions"]/vdx_access_table["BOOKED_IMP#BOOKED_ENG"] choices_vdx_cpcv = "

Comment: it identify `isin` with `np.where`

Comment: So if the ['COST_TYPE']==CPM, which calculation it will perform?. Sorry if I'm bothering you. however, it's quite important to know.

Comment: It is no calculation, it is boolean mask

Comment: it's not providing the correct output. where the ['COST_TYPE] is CPM or CPCV it actually needs to perform this "choices_vdx_cpcv" and if ['COST_TYPE] is CPE or CPE+ need to perform this "choices_vdx_eng " on same column "Delivery%". my edited code doing that, however, it's printing like attached screenshot.

Comment: and if no `CPM or CPCV or CPE or CPE+` what is output?

Comment: I get it, give me a secon

Comment: @dharmendramishra - please check edited answer. need 2 boolean mask

Comment: Yes, that's working, you made my day. thank you so much.

Comment: @dharmendramishra - you are welcome! Can you upvote my solution?

Comment: @dharmendramishra - upvote i think click to small traingle above `0` ;)

Comment: did it, hoping it worked this time. downvote clicked by mistake:)

Comment: @dharmendramishra - No problem. ;) Nice day!